# Comparison Fuzzy R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-mining, data-science, text-mining

I have two datasets, the dataset df1 has a column with the names of companies registered in our CRM and another column with the name of the sales manager. Dataset df2 has a column with the names of companies that have visited an IT event.

The dataset df2, because it was manually entered by the participants, was written with spelling mistakes, abbreviations, etc. That is, similar names for the names of companies registered in CRM.

So the goal is to compare the names of the companies that visited the event in dataset df2, with the names of the companies registered in the dataset df1 and assign these comparisons to the sales manager. Of course, names that are not found or that have a very distant comparison should have the NA value for the salesperson.

I'm new to R and I'm trying various things with little success.

Could you help me build this script?

Below is the example:

```
                 df1                                 df2  
    |----------------|----------------|       |----------------|
    |    Company     |  Sales Manager |       | Company Event  |
    |----------------|----------------|       |----------------|
    |Customer 1 SA   |Erik            |       |Customer 1      |
    |Customer 2 S\A  |Selma           |       |Customer 1 SA.  |
    |Customer 3 Ltda.|Juca            |       |Customer2       |
    |Customer 4      |Batista         |       |cUSTOIMER 3     |
    |----------------|----------------|       |Customer 10     |
                                              |----------------|
```

The final result expected is to have another df with crossed data.

```
                             matched df  
        |----------------|----------------|----------------|
        | Company Event  |    Company     | Sales Manager  |
        |----------------|----------------|----------------|
        |Customer 1      |Customer 1 SA   |Erik            |
        |Customer 1 SA.  |Customer 1 SA   |Erik            |
        |Customer2       |Customer 2 S\A  |Selma           |
        |cUSTOIMER 3     |Customer 3 Ltda.|Juca            |
        |Customer 10     |NA              |NA              |
        |----------------|----------------|----------------|
```

Comment: At least show what you have tried. Now you are just asking to write the code for you. You might want to look into the `stringdist` or `fuzzyjoin` packages and search SO for fuzzyjoin or fuzzy match.

Comment: I'm asking for a help, I tried to use the 'adist' package. But many combinations do not make sense.
Thanks for the tip, I'll search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work. It involves cleaning names, getting the minimum distances, and then getting the sales manager information.

```
library(stringdist)
# declare data ------------------------------------------------------------
Company <- c("Customer 1 SA" ,"Customer 2 S/A", "Customer 3 Ltda.", "Customer 4")   
SalesManager <- c("Erik", "Selma", "Juca", "Batista")
CompanyEvent <- c("Customer 1", "Customer 1 SA.", "Customer2" , "cUSTOIMER 3", "Customer 10")
df1 <- data.frame(Company, SalesManager, stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(CompanyEvent, stringsAsFactors = F)

# clean 'dirty' names -----------------------------------------------------
df1$cleannames <- gsub("S/A", "", df1$Company)
df1$cleannames <- gsub("SA", "", df1$cleannames)
df1$cleannames <- gsub("Ltda.", "", df1$cleannames)
df1$cleannames <- gsub(" ", "", df1$cleannames)
df1$cleannames <-tolower(df1$cleannames)

df2$cleannames  <- gsub("S/A", "", df2$CompanyEvent)
df2$cleannames <- gsub("SA", "", df2$cleannames)
df2$cleannames <- gsub("Ltda.", "", df2$cleannames)
df2$cleannames <- gsub(" ", "", df2$cleannames)
df2$cleannames <-tolower(df2$cleannames)

# Get the closest matches and distances -----------------------------------
df2$closestentry <- apply(df2,1, function(x) df1$cleannames[which.min(stringdist(x["cleannames"], df1$cleannames ))] )
df2$levdistance <- apply(df2,1, function(x) min(stringdist(x["cleannames"], df1$cleannames )))

#Get sales mgr data using closest matches
df2$salesmgr <- df1$SalesManager[match(df2$closestentry,df1$cleannames )]
df2
> df2
    CompanyEvent cleannames closestentry levdistance salesmgr
1     Customer 1  customer1    customer1           0     Erik
2 Customer 1 SA. customer1.    customer1           1     Erik
3      Customer2  customer2    customer2           0    Selma
4    cUSTOIMER 3 custoimer3    customer3           1     Juca
5    Customer 10 customer10    customer1           1     Erik
```

Fuzzy string matching is .. well, fuzzy, so you might have cases that are not what you expect, however you should be fine after a bit of tweaking (here that would be adding `customer10` into `df1` for example)

What I mean here by distance is the string distance, see `?stringdist`

Comment: Why does this answer have a downvote, it looks usable?

Comment: How I hate downvoting without leaving a comment what to improve